# Why does my post req fail while the form works?

Tags: python, url, python-requests

```
    Im tying to access this webpage via a post request 



    <form name="codfiscalForm" method="POST" action="/apps/infocodfiscal.html" abframeid="iframe.0.621769191076827" abineguid="2888C5AB133349C88752FA692B0A3B67">
    </form>
    <input type="hidden" name="pagina" value="domenii">
    <input name="B1" type="submit" class="form1" value="VIZUALIZARE">
```

The incorporated form works as expected.However when I try to get the html via a post request from an outside script i cannot access it as the website throws me an error
My script is:

```
import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

res = requests.get("https://mfinante.gov.ro/apps/infocodfiscal.html", data="")
print(res.content)
```

Comment: The website doesn't like your `User-Agent` header and resets the connection. You need to mock a device user-agent that the target website is happy with.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Issue when downloading image from url with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68106576/issue-when-downloading-image-from-url-with-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by [Chillie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4570170/chillie)  you need to pass User-Agent header to download the page.

Try this:

```
import requests

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.106 Safari/537.36'}

response = requests.get('https://mfinante.gov.ro/apps/infocodfiscal.html', headers=headers)
print(response.text)
```